# Starting out and new to SSRS -- How do I "deploy the report" and add a web reference?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS.  I have gone through some tutorials in the online Microsoft "docs" pages and I have seen how to create a report.  Now, I am looking at a tutorial (on a different web site) with eager anticipation to start making programmatically generated reports of my own.  This tutorial has these two first steps:

```
    Step 1: Create and deploy the report. 

    Step 2: Add a web reference to the web services exposed by Reporting Services 2005, i.e., ReportExecution2005 and ReportService2005.
```

So, I know how to create a report (by hand), but, how do I deploy the report?

And how exactly do I add a web reference to the web service exposed by Reporting Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Deploy:**

In the reporting services project, set the TargetServerURL property to your Reporting Services server (typically `http://<servername>/reportserver`), then Build>Deploy to deploy all reports in the project or right-click on a single report and choose to deploy just that report  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/publishing-reports-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017 for screenshots and more details.

**Web References:**

If you're following tutorials that expect a web reference and you're using Visual Studio 2017, go to Project>Add Service Reference, click "Advanced...", then "Add Web Reference..." (older versions of Visual Studio had "Add Web Reference" as an option on the Project Menu but it's harder to find in VS2017)  For ReportExecution, the path is usually `http://<servername>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx` ReportService should be the same except replace "Execution" with "Service" in the name.

**Example Usage:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render?view=sqlserver-2016 has a detailed example of saving a report to MHTML in VB or C# using the ReportExecution service (you can pick the language from the `</>` button near the top/right of the page). You can also save to PDF and other various formats - see the "format" parameter notes in this link